# Как изменить Title одного activity из другого?

Tags: android

Есть два activity, первое запускает второе через intent.

```
Intent intentSettings = new Intent(getContext(), Settings.class);
startActivity(intentSettings);
```

Во втором есть метод

```
public void changeTitle(View v){
    Как здесь вызвать setTitle("Название") первого.
}
```

Comment: можно при переходе через интент слать данные для title другого и сетить при инициализации активити

Comment: Есть пример как это?

Answer (score 4):

В первом нужно вызвать

```
public void runActivity(){
  int CHANGE_TITLE = 1000;
  Intent intentSettings = new Intent(getContext(), Settings.class);
  startActivityForResult(intentSettings, CHANGE_TITLE);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (data == null) {return;}
    String title = data.getStringExtra("title");
    getActivity().setTitle(title);
}
```

А во втором

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.putExtra("title", title);
    setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Тогда при возвращение изменится название окна.

Comment: Одно замечание, `CHANGE_TITLE` лучше делать глобальной переменной, чтобы использовать ее значение в разных методах. В `onActivityResult` нужно сравнить `requestCode` с `CHANGE_TITLE`, иначе если вы добавите в дальнейшем взаимодействием с другими активити, будите получать ошибку.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый.

Answer (score 2):

При переходе на другую активность вы используете intent:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(your_activity_1.this, your_activity_2.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

дальше вам нужно передеть через intent данные для title:

```
intent.putExtra("title", "Значение");
```

и в функции `onCreate()` вы перехватываете данные  для title и меняете его:

```
setTitle(getIntent().getStringExtra("title));
```

либо другой вариант:

```
getSupportActionBar().setTitle(getIntent().getStringExtra("title));
```

надеюсь что один из методов поможет.

Comment: Это не то. Название нужно изменить у первого а не у второго.

Comment: из какого куда вы переходите?

Comment: Во втором есть кнопка изменить название. После нажатия должно изменится название(его нельзя увидеть так как второе сверху) только после закрытия второго.

Comment: вы не сможете увидеть результат нажатия на кнопку без перехода на другое активити, а при переходе можно спокойно сетить нужное вам название в onCreate(), вы можете перейти как-то из одного активити в другое, и соответственно передать значение title

Comment: Допустим я нажал кнопку назад onBackPressed()

Comment: ну значит туда тоже забросить нужно переход по intent, самый простой способ менять title это через intent

Comment: Как через него изменить Название

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92021/discussion-between-andrew-goroshko-and-s-oleg).

Answer (score 0):

Вот вариант который я использую:
SharedPrefManager

```
private static final String TITLE = "title";
```

метод для хранения Заголовка

```
public boolean setTitle(String title){
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = mCtx.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_NAME,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor=sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putString(TITLE, title);
    editor.apply();

    return true;
}
```

метод для чтения из хранилища

```
public String getTitle(){
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = mCtx.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_NAME,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    return sharedPreferences.getString(TITLE,null);
}
```

Для установки заголовка

```
getSupportActionBar().setTitle(!TextUtils.isEmpty(SharedPrefManager.getmInstance(this).getTitle()) ? SharedPrefManager.getmInstance(this).getTitle() : "Default title");
```

в случае когда вам нужно дефолтный тайтл то удаляем наш встроенный тайтл с помощью

```
public void clearData(String key){
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = mCtx.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_NAME,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    sharedPreferences.edit().remove(key).commit();
}
```